# How to make scrollable plot area fill all chart's background area in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How to make scrollable plot area fill all chart's background area?

The backgorund area of the graphic is getting two colors: the initial with the color of the background of the graphic and the one extended with the background color of the page.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    scrollablePlotArea: {
        minWidth: 700,
        scrollPositionX: 1
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'Scrollable plot area'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Open on mobile and scroll sideways'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        overflow: 'justify'
    }
},
yAxis: {
    tickWidth: 1,
    title: {
        text: 'Wind speed (m/s)'
    },
    lineWidth: 1,
    opposite: true
},
tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' m/s'
},

plotOptions: {
    spline: {
        lineWidth: 4,
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 5
            }
        },
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        pointInterval: 3600000, // one hour
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 4, 31, 0, 0, 0)
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Hestavollane',
    data: [0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1.3, 1.5, 2.9, 1.9, 2.6, 1.6, 3, 4, 3.6,
        5.5, 6.2, 5.5, 4.5, 4, 3.1, 2.7, 4, 2.7, 2.3, 2.3, 4.1, 7.7, 7.1,
        5.6, 6.1, 5.8, 8.6, 7.2, 9, 10.9, 11.5, 11.6, 11.1, 12, 12.3, 10.7,
        9.4, 9.8, 9.6, 9.8, 9.5, 8.5, 7.4, 7.6]

}, {
    name: 'Vik',
    data: [0, 0, 0.6, 0.9, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.2,
        0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.2,
        0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 3.1, 3.1, 2.5, 1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1, 2.3, 1.9, 1.2,
        0.7, 1.3, 0.4, 0.3]
}]
```

});

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbog6ep5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two (or more) ways out of that, by `JS` and by `CSS`.
You can set the c`hart.chartBackground` width equal to `'100%'` inside of `chart.events.load` event function, just like that:

```
chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    scrollablePlotArea: {
        minWidth: 700,
        scrollPositionX: 1
    },
    events: {
        load() {
        this.chartBackground.attr({
            width: '100%'
        })
      }
    }
},
```

or by setting it in your CSS file:

```
.highcharts-background {
  width: 100%
}
```

Both of them works good, but the second one is more efficient.

Live examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/sryp2km6/ (JS)

http://jsfiddle.net/pvzs2amr/ (CSS)

Best regards!